# How to track bitcoin transaction on PC

Tags: transactions, blockchain, tracking

I am still quite new to Bitcoin, and my question may be a little bit stupid. So I am wondering how can I track the transaction or the newest block on my computer. I know there are tons of websites showing the real-time information, so I guess my question is like is there any way I can type something on my terminal of the PC and shows the data on it? Something like constructed the dataset on my own.

Answer (score 1):

> **how can I track the transaction or the newest block on my computer.**

You can run a full-node Bitcoin client such as Bitcoin core. It will collect the full blockchain - it can take a long time (weeks) to download the full blockchain, but you should be able to examine early blocks and transactions without waiting.

In the case of Bitcoin Core, you can use the [API](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#bitcoin-core-apis) to examine blocks (`GetBlock` etc) and transactions (`GetTransaction` etc).

> **is there any way I can type something on my terminal of the PC and shows the data on it?**

For example

```
./bitcoin-cli getblockcount

./bitcoin-cli -testnet getblockhash 240886

./bitcoin-cli getblock 00000000000000000d2347b601158f40c741dbd9353918903f057cedd82f49de 2
```